# Seleccionar/Deseleccionar elementos

Tags: jquery

Estoy intentando implementar una opción para seleccionar/deseleccionar un dibujo (cada dibujo sería un producto). Y de entrada lo he conseguido, lo puedo hacer uno a uno, o mediante un botón que selecciona o deselecciona todo.

El problema es que cuando he clicado uno y luego clico otro muchas veces he de clicar un par de veces encima para que se produzca la acción que deseo (seleccionar/deseleccionar según su estado actual). Eso tengo claro que es por no tener el código todo lo correcto que debería.

¿Como se solucionaría?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Seleccionar/Deseleccionar de manera individual
  Marca_Individual_Seleccionada = false;

  //Recibe el evento de que se ha clicado Logo_Marca
  $(".Logo_Marca").click(function() {

    if (Marca_Individual_Seleccionada == true) {

      $(this).removeClass("Marca_Seleccionada");
      Marca_Individual_Seleccionada = false;

    } else {

      $(this).addClass("Marca_Seleccionada");
      Marca_Individual_Seleccionada = true;

    }

  });

  // Seleccionar/Deseleccionar TODO a la vez
  Seleccionar_Todo = false;

  $("#Boton_Marca_Seleccionar_Todo").click(function() {
    if (Seleccionar_Todo == false) {
      $(".Logo_Marca").addClass("Marca_Seleccionada")
      Seleccionar_Todo = true;
    } else {
      $(".Logo_Marca").removeClass("Marca_Seleccionada")
      Seleccionar_Todo = false;
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: Hola Carlos, ¿al seleccionar de forma individual permites también la selección múltiple o solo deseas seleccionar uno o todos pero no dos por ejemplo?

Comment: Hola @Edu3D no termino de entender muy bien tu pregunta. Yo permito que no haya nada seleccionado, todo, uno, dos o los que el usuario quisiera. Es más, podría empezar de manera individual y luego pensar que quiere todos y entonces apretar el botón, o cualquier combinación que se te ocurra. Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: te acabo de enviar un ejemplo simple de como seleccionar y deseleccionar con el **toggleClass**. Pruebalo en tu código y nos dice. PD: Lo he puesto en un ejemplo para mostrarlo en el fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te doy un ejemplo un poco diferente de lo que tienes pero funciona de forma más simple:

```js
// Seleccionar/Deseleccionar TODO a la vez
Seleccionar_Todo = false;

$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".objetos").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("seleccionados");
    if ($('.objetos').length == $('.seleccionados').length) {
      Seleccionar_Todo = true;
    } else {
      Seleccionar_Todo = false;
    }
  });


  $("#Boton_Marca_Seleccionar_Todo").click(function() {
    if (Seleccionar_Todo == false) {
      $(".objetos").addClass("seleccionados");
      Seleccionar_Todo = true;
    } else {
      $(".objetos").removeClass("seleccionados");
      Seleccionar_Todo = false;
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.lista {
  display: block;
  padding: 1cm;
}

.objetos {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #555;
  background: #428bca;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.seleccionados {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="lista">
  <div class="objetos">

  </div>
  <div class="objetos">

  </div>
  <div class="objetos">

  </div>
  <div class="objetos seleccionados">

  </div>
</div>
<button id="Boton_Marca_Seleccionar_Todo">
SELECCIONAR TODO
</button>
```

Comment: Wow, lo he puesto poniendo mi clases y va perfecto. Ya se que no se ha de usar esto para dar simplemente las gracias, pero muchas gracias, me has dado un enfoque muy diferente al mío.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es por que la inicializacion de las variables se encuentran dentro de la funcion, prueba a definirlas como globales a ver si de esa forma funciona al primer click.

```
  // Seleccionar/Deseleccionar de manera individual
  Marca_Individual_Seleccionada = false;

  // Seleccionar/Deseleccionar TODO a la vez
  Seleccionar_Todo = false;

$(document).ready(function() {

  //Recibe el evento de que se ha clicado Logo_Marca
  $(".Logo_Marca").click(function() {

    if (Marca_Individual_Seleccionada == true) {

      $(this).removeClass("Marca_Seleccionada");
      Marca_Individual_Seleccionada = false;

    } else {

      $(this).addClass("Marca_Seleccionada");
      Marca_Individual_Seleccionada = true;

    }

  });


  $("#Boton_Marca_Seleccionar_Todo").click(function() {
    if (Seleccionar_Todo == false) {
      $(".Logo_Marca").addClass("Marca_Seleccionada")
      Seleccionar_Todo = true;
    } else {
      $(".Logo_Marca").removeClass("Marca_Seleccionada")
      Seleccionar_Todo = false;
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: Eso ya lo he probado y no cambia en nada el resultado aparentemente. :(