# Marcar elemento y desmarcar si se marca otro distinto

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

tengo array de productos que contiene un array de tallas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que estoy tratando de hacer mediante JS que al pulsar en una talla se ponga de color negro como ven aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que toda la talla que selecciono se pone negra y yo quiero hacer que únicamente una talla se ponga negra. Es decir, que si marco una esa se ponga negra y el resto se queden en blanco y si pulso otra la que habia pulsado anteriormente ahora es blanca y la recien pulsada negra.

Algo parecido a lo de este post:

[Seleccionar/Deseleccionar elementos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99664/seleccionar-deseleccionar-elementos)

Pero que se vayan deseleccionando una si se selecciona otra.

el HTML:

```
<div id="stock-size-{{$stock->id}}" class="stock-size" onclick="changeText({{$stock->id}})">
<span>{{$stock->size}}</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function changeText(id) {
    var stock_size = document.querySelector("#stock-size-" + id);
    var stock_size_span = document.querySelector("#stock-size-" + id + " span");
    stock_size.style.borderStyle = "none";
    stock_size.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    stock_size_span.style.color = "white";
}
```

Alguna ayuda sobre como puedo hacer esto? gracias

EDIT:

```
                    @foreach($product->stocks->sortBy('size') as $stock)
                    @if($stock->quantity>0)
                    <div class="all-sizes">

                        <form method="POST" name="stock-size-{{$stock->id}}" action="{{route('cart.add', ['id' => $product->id])}}">
                            @csrf
                            <div id="stock-size-{{$stock->id}}" class="stock-size" onclick="changeText(event,{{$stock->id}})">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="stock-size" value="{{$stock->size}} required">
                                    <span>{{$stock->size}}</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" class="addCart" id="addCart-{{$product->id}}" value="Add to Cart"/>
                        </form>

                    </div>
                    @else
                    <p class='no-stock'>{{$stock->size}}</p>
                    @endif
                    @endforeach
```

Comment: Deberías tener un ciclo para generar los radios y, aparte, los que pertenecen a un mismo producto deben compartir el nombre, por ejemplo: `name="stock-size-{{$stock->id}}"`

Comment: Lo he probado poniendole el name al formulario pero aun así no me funciona, no entiendo el por qué ya que si quito la linea del formulario funciona perfectamente. Edito el código, echale un vistazo a ver si podemos solucionarlo... gracias

Comment: Tienes algunos errores en ese código, revisa la respuesta actualizada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo adecuado para este caso es usar *inputs* tipo radio, porque solo se puede seleccionar uno y basta con un poco de CSS para lograrlo:

1. Debes encerrar el radio y span dentro de una etiqueta (label)
2. El radio no será visible, pero, un clic en la etiqueta (el span pertenece a la etiqueta), hará que se seleccione
3. Se usa el estado del radio cuando está marcado y se asocia el span mediante el selector "virgulilla" (prime en inglés) `~` como [hermano, hijo del mismo padre](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_hermanos_generales) para aplicar los cambios

```js
// Si necesitas validar o hacer algo con el valor seleccionado
function changeText(e, id) {
    // Solo si el clic fue en un radio
    if(e.target.tagName == 'INPUT') {
        // Obtener contenedor
        let stockSize = document.querySelector("#stock-size-" + id);
        // Obtener valor seleccionado
        let radio = stockSize.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked');
        let value = (radio && radio.value) ? radio.value : false;
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

```css
/* Solo para separar un poco, aplica tus propios estilos */
.stock-size {
    padding:10px;
}
/* Los radios dentro de etiqueta no son visibles */
.stock-size label input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}
/* Estilos generales de spans cuando el radio no está seleccionado */
.stock-size label span {
    color:black;
    background:white;
    border:1px black solid;
    margin:2px 5px;
    padding:2px 5px;
}
/* Cambiar span cuando el radio está deshabilitado */
.stock-size label input[type="radio"]:disabled ~ span {
    color:#ccc;
    background:#777;
}
/* Cambiar span cuando se selecciona un radio */
.stock-size label input[type="radio"]:checked ~ span {
    color:white;
    background:black;
}
```

```html
<div id="stock-size-x" class="stock-size" onclick="changeText(event, 'x');">
  Elemento X:
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="stock-size-x" value="19">
    <span>19</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="stock-size-x" value="30" disabled>
    <span>30</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="stock-size-x" value="32">
    <span>32</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="stock-size-x" value="35">
    <span>35</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div id="stock-size-y" class="stock-size" onclick="changeText(event, 'y');">
  Elemento Y:
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="stock-size-y" value="19">
    <span>19</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="stock-size-y" value="30">
    <span>30</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="stock-size-y" value="32">
    <span>32</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="stock-size-y" value="35" disabled>
    <span>35</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Me parece que estás creando un formulario para cada talla, revisa los comentarios para ver todos los cambios:

```
                <!-- El contenedor debe estar fuera del ciclo -->
                <div class="all-sizes">
                    <!-- formulario y div con ID de producto -->
                    <form method="POST" name="stock-size-{{$product->id}}" action="{{route('cart.add', ['id' => $product->id])}}">
                        @csrf
                        <div id="stock-size-{{$product->id}}" class="stock-size" onclick="changeText(event,{{$product->id}})">
                <!-- Solo las opciones dentro del ciclo -->
                @foreach($product->stocks->sortBy('size') as $stock)
                @if($stock->quantity>0)
                            <!-- Solo etiqueta, input y span dentro -->
                            <label>
                                <!-- Tenías error en valor y required, por no cerrar correctamente las comillas -->
                                <input type="radio" name="stock-size" value="{{$stock->size}}" required>
                                <span>{{$stock->size}}</span>
                            </label>
                @else
                        <!-- No hay radio, esto se verá diferente -->
                        <p class='no-stock'>{{$stock->size}}</p>
                @endif
                @endforeach
                        <!-- Cierre de contenedores -->
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="addCart" id="addCart-{{$product->id}}" value="Add to Cart"/>
                    </form>

                </div>
```

Cuando no hay stock, deberías mostrar el radio, pero deshabilitado y, con CSS se pueden aplicar colores diferentes. Modifiqué el fragmento de código para que veas cómo funciona.

Desconozco laravel, pero creo que puedes crear los radios con un [operador ternario](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), donde, si el stock es mayor que cero, se agrega 'required', de lo contrario, se deshabilita:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="stock-size" value="{{$stock->size}}" {{ ($stock->quantity > 0) ? 'required' : 'disabled' }}>
    <span>{{$stock->size}}</span>
</label>
```

Comment: muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola @Triby perdona que te escriba de nuevo. ¿Por qué al incluir el label dentro de un Formulario el botón unico deja de funciona y se vuelven a pintar todos? Te dejo el código en un edit

Comment: Ahora sí, arreglado, muchas gracias! fue un fallo mío y sin querer cambié el ID del onclick y puse el order ID en lugar del product ID, muchas gracias!